# Can one website request to see cookies of another?

Tags: security, cookies, session-cookies

Let's say we have two websites: `GoodGuys.com` and `BadGuys.com`

If a user visits `BadGuys.com`, could this website subsequently make a request to view cookies from `GoodGuys.com`?

Comment: I would like to ask better questions. Could someone say the reason why this question is downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without some sort of exploit of the browser, I don't believe so.

It is possible for badly coded websites to have a comment section, for example, that a malicious user could type in some javascript, which would be executed by any user who views it could post cookies to another place...

Comment: What could be the consequence for posting cookies to 'another place'?

Comment: Could post your session to another server which could then be used to authenticate and impersonate you, and if you've got personal information or stored card details, all potentially available to the attacker.

It's the reason places like amazon ask you to put in your password again before clicking submit payment.